# Не могу передать юзера в модель. DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня для создания профиля требуется User

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    ...
```

Есть сериализатор:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Сериализатор профиля юзера

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'user', 'name', 'surname', 
            'patronymic', 'kind', 'regions', 
            'phone', 'company', 'categories'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        return profile
```

Но почему-то я не могу передать поле "user" в сериализатор. **Views**:

```py
class ProfileCreate(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # Наполнение профиля юзера

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.user = request.user
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        profile = serializer.save()
        return Response(ProfileSerializer(profile))
```

В чём же моя ошибка или непонимание?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена.**
Следовало просто убрать в сериализаторе из ***fields*** поле ***user***, для того чтобы оно стало необязательным.
Благодаря методу create в сериализаторе юзер сохраняется.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передавать пользователя при сохранении:

```
serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Уже делал, не работает